# Problem css; round circle over component - Email template

Tags: css, xml, html-email, qweb

I need to put a circle on a card for a mailing

[image]

but I can't put styles like these for mailing:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-58%) translateY(-75%);
```

I opted to use `margin-top` but it doesn't work either!

Actually, I have:

[image]

My code is:
..code header

```
<tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="590" style="min-width: 590px; color: white;padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px; border-collapse:separate; background-color:#5619A4;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 13px;">
                                            <div align="center">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="590" style="max-width: 50px; color: white;padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px; border-collapse:separate; background-color:transparent;margin-top:-12%;width: 25px;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td >
                                                            <div style="max-width: 75%;background-color:white;border-radius: 16px;margin: 12%;background-color: transparent;">
                                                                <div align="center"><!--[if mso]>
                                                                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="margin-top:-10%;height:100px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:100px;" arcsize="600%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ff8080">
                                                                <w:anchorlock/>
                                                                <center>
                                                                <![endif]-->
                                                                  <a href="http://"
                                                                  style="background-color:#ff8080;border-radius:50%;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:100px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:100px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">1</a>
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                                </center>
                                                                </v:roundrect>
                                                                <![endif]--></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
```

Comment: If nobody can produce a slab of code for this, do check out this HTML email solution, with one of the keys being a max-height:0 (or smaller than the other section) to produce the overlap, and the other main being opacity:0.999 to generate a stacking context (in place of position). https://codepen.io/matthieuSolente/pen/QWMLeZW

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, support for absolute positioning is pretty bad across email clients. But it can be emulated using the `max-height` property and the [faux absolute position](https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position) technique.

Here’s a full example of what you're trying to achieve based on your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <title>Overlap</title>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto; width:590px; background:#fff;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!--[if mso]>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="width:100%;"><tr><td style="font-size:0; height:50px;">
                    <v:oval xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:245px; width:100px; height:100px; v-text-anchor:middle;" fillcolor="#ff8080" stroke="false">
                        <v:textbox style="color:#fff;">
                            1
                        </v:textbox>
                    </v:oval>
                </td></tr></table>
                <![endif]-->
                <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                <div style="max-height:50px; text-align:center;">
                    <div style="display:inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; border-radius:50px; background-color:#ff8080; text-align:center; font:bold 16px/100px sans-serif; color:#fff;">
                        1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto; width:100%; background:#5619a4;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:16px; padding-top:66px;">
                            <p style="margin:0; color:#fff; font:16px/24px sans-serif;">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolore alias accusamus repudiandae soluta, provident nam aut iste! Facilis, blanditiis, voluptatum.
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thxs, solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

How about using **position: relative** ?

The tag `a` would have these rules:

```
background-color: white;
border-radius:50%;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
bottom: -75px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding: 0;
color: black;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
```

You can adjust how much of the circle overlaps with `bottom: -75px;`

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="590" style="min-width: 590px; color: white;padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px; border-collapse:separate; background-color:#5619A4;">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td valign="top" style="font-size: 13px;">
                                            <div align="center">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="590" style=" color: white; border-collapse:separate; background-color:transparent;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div style="">
                                                                <div align="center" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
                                                                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="margin-top:-10%;height:100px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:100px;" arcsize="600%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ff8080">
                                                                <w:anchorlock/>
                                                                <center>
                                                                <![endif]-->
                                                                  <a href="http://" style="background-color: white;border-radius:50%;color:#ffffff;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:100px;height: 100px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;display: block;position: relative;margin: 0 auto;bottom: -75px;left: 0;right: 0;padding: 0;color: black;line-height: 50px;text-align: center;">1</a>
                                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                                </center>
                                                                </v:roundrect>
                                                                <![endif]--></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
```

Comment: @Chatemor It happens that email services like GMAIL block styles (like position: relative/absolute), since I put the styles you give me and they don't show up.